# Java - How to insert data using postman

Tags: java, spring-mvc, postman

My code is running perfect but at the postman side showing error

> "The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers."

while posted data is coming in `restController`,`serviceImpl` and in `Studentimpl` too.

My `restController` Is

```
        @RequestMapping(value="save",method=RequestMethod.POST,produces="application/json")

        GetStudentSaveResponse saveResponse(@RequestBody GetStudentSaveRequest saveRequest)
        {
            System.out.println(saveRequest.getName());
            System.out.println(saveRequest.getAddress());
            return serviceIntf.saveResponse(saveRequest);
        }
         RestImpl is
         @Override
        public GetStudentSaveResponse saveResponse(GetStudentSaveRequest saveRequest) {
                GetStudentSaveResponse saveResponse = new GetStudentSaveResponse();
                studentIntf.SaveStudent(saveRequest.getName(), saveRequest.getAddress());           
                System.out.println("SERVICE"+saveRequest.getName());
                return saveResponse;
            }
```

Implementation class is:

```
public void SaveStudent(String name, String address) {
    try
    {
        java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
        con=jdbctemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();

        CallableStatement call = con.prepareCall("{Student_pro(?,?,?,?,?)}");
        call.setString(1, "insertStudent");
        call.setInt(2, 0);
        call.setString(3, name);
        call.setString(4, address);
        call.setDate(5, date);

        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(address);

    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Controller class is annotated with the following

```
@Controller
@EnableWebMvc
```

You are getting HTTP 406, which indicates the media type is incorrect. Set the content type as application/json as shown below

[image]

**Update:**

The issue is, if you want to return an Object from your POST method, use `ResponseEntity<Object>` instead of directly using Object. Hence, in this case you change your return type to `ResponseEntity<GetStudentSaveResponse>`

Comment: getting same error after adding Those anotations and setting postman as you said

Comment: use ResponseEntity<GetStudentSaveResponse> as return type and change code accordingly